# Populate a column with widgets from a set

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a column with various widgets:

```
Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(title),
          Text(subtitle),
         

        ],
      )
```

Now, after Text(subtitle), I want to add widgets from a Set variable, but not creating another column, more or less like this:

```
Set<ListTile> _myList = {}; // with many ListTiles

return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(title),
          Text(subtitle),

         _myList,

        ],
      );
```

But this isn't correct. How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the spread operator(identified as 3 dots) to add list of widget to column children.

```
return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(title),
          Text(subtitle),

         ..._myList,

        ],
      );
```

Comment: I cannot find certain documantation but there is a link https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-using-triple-dot-spread-operator-examples

Comment: It is called a `spread operator`. You can find it here in the official dart docs https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists